# What is $\inf\limits_{k\ge n}~ k^{2}\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{k}]}$ ? where $\chi$ is the indicator function.

Tags: real-analysis

I have been given an answer :
$$\inf\limits_{k\ge n}~ k^{2}\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{k}]} = n\chi_{\{0\}}$$
but I cannot tell why. And my guess
$$\inf\limits_{k\ge n}~ k^{2}\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{k}]} = \bigcap\limits_{k\ge n} \{k^{2}, 0\} = \{0\}$$
dose not work.

Any advice is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $t < 0$, then clearly $k^2\chi_{[0,1/k]}(t) = 0$ for every $k$.

If $t > 0$, then clearly $k^2\chi_{[0,1/k]}(t) = 0$ for all sufficiently large $k$ (i.e. for $k > t$).

So look at $t = 0$. Here $\chi_{[0,1/k]}(t) = 1$ for every $k$. So
$$
k^2\chi_{[0,1/k]}(0) = k^2
$$
Taking infimums over $k \geq n$ gives 
$$
\inf_{k \geq n}k^2\chi_{[0,1/k]}(0) = n^2
$$
Thus the result is the function which is $n^2$ when the input is 0 and 0 otherwise,i.e.
$$
n^2\chi_{\{0\}}.
$$
So actually I disagree with what you've written as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  This is an infimum of functions, i.e. $\inf_{k \geq n} k^2\chi_{[0, \frac{1}{k}]}$ just means the function which is $t \to \inf_{k \geq n} \chi_{[0, \frac{1}{k}]}(t)$ for every $t\in \mathbb{R}.$

For $t>0$, eventually $\frac{1}{k} < t$.

If $t=0$, then $n^2 \leq k^2$ for all $k \geq n$.

And if $t<0$, then $\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{k}]}(t)=0$ for all $k$.